# Shortcut to hide the desktop icons in GNOME 3

Tags: shortcut-keys, icons, gnome-shell, desktop-icons

I can hide/show the desktop icons using `gnome-tweaks` (see the picture, "Afficher les icônes" means "Display Icons").

[image: Gnome-Tweak]

I would like to know how to set up a shortcut doing that ? I use GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04.

There is a shortcut to hide all windows (<kbd>Windows-key</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>), so why not one for hiding/showing the desktop icons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a small script, which changes this option:

```
#!/bin/sh
if $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons);
then new="false";
else new="true";
fi
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons $new
```

You can save the script `/somewhere/as/somewaht.sh` (with permission to execute) and then add in your keyboardsettings an entry:
[image: Keyboardsettings]

Comment: Nice, you can shorten it to `if $(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons); then gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false; else gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true; fi`.